# How to show posts have more than 5 votes and be posted in 1hour?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

this is what I write, which is working well with show only the post has been posted in 1 hour,

```
def feed
  Micropost.where("created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now - 10.minutes)
end
```

my micropost model:

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :votes, as: :voteable
    ...

  def total_votes
    self.up_votes - self.down_votes
  end

  def up_votes
    self.votes.where(vote: true).size
  end

  def down_votes
    self.votes.where(vote: false).size
  end
end
```

my vote model

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :voteable, polymorphic: true
  validates_uniqueness_of :user, scope: [:voteable_id, :voteable_type]
end
```

Related Link:[Render posts both by time desc and total_votes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28403479/render-posts-both-by-time-desc-and-total-votes)

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but you can say `10.minutes.ago` instead of `Time.zone.now - 10.minutes`. Please show use your `Micropost` model and how a `Vote` relates to it.

Comment: @KyleDecot ty for ur comments, updated ：）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like this solution since it requires multiple hits against your database but with small numbers (hundreds or even thousands) of items it should work just fine.

```
def feed
  posts = Micropost.where("votes>=5 and created_at >= ?", 1.hour.ago)
  return posts.select { |post| post.total_votes > 5 }
end
```

Comment: hi, ty for ur answer, but since i make this vote model as voteable, rails shows error "no such column: votes:"

Comment: Which gem are you using to add voteable?  You can likely obtain a list of micro posts and then filter that with a map call.