# Render posts both by time desc and total_votes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to render posts in feed first by total_votes on this post, if no votes or same votes, ordered by time desc, means the new post will be higher. My attempting codes is here.

```
def feed
  microposts = Micropost.where("created_at >= ? ", 30.minutes.ago).order('created_at desc')
end
```

---

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
  <ol class="microposts">
    <%= render @feed_items.sort_by { |post| post.total_votes }.reverse%>
  </ol>
   <%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
<% end %>
```

---

edit:

I am sorry that the total_votes is only a method in my Micropost Model.

Micropost Model

```
  class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :votes, as: :voteable
     ...

     def total_votes
       self.up_votes - self.down_votes
     end

     def up_votes
       self.votes.where(vote: true).size
     end

     def down_votes
       self.votes.where(vote: false).size
     end
```

Sorry again .-.

edit 2:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fgx3J.png

Comment: Just try this if this works for you: `Micropost.where("created_at >= ? ", 30.minutes.ago).order('total_votes desc, created_at desc')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers are right, but just for fun, you could also sort it in your view.

Change:

```
@feed_items.sort_by { |post| post.total_votes }
```

To:

```
@feed_items.sort { |x,y| if x.total_votes < y.total_votes; 1 elsif x.total_votes == y.total_votes; y.created_at <=> x.created_at else; -1 end } %>
```

Comment: Thank u for answer, I tried to make that changes on my code, but its not worked. The first post is the oldest post .-.

Comment: If its putting later dates first, just switch x.created_at <=> y.created_at around. It'll be y.created_at <=> x.created_at

Comment: One thing is wired, when I use this code on my app, the post which get highest vote is at the bottom, due to its also the newest post.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. If you're saying that the array is sorted, but everything is reversed, then you can just put .reverse at the end like you did in your original code. If that's not what you mean, could you clarify?

Comment: The things is that, every thing works fine after i swap y.created_at and x.created_at, but the post with highest votes is at the bottom.

Comment: Okay, you can do two things. Option 1: Switch the -1 and the positive 1 in the sort block.  Option 2: undo the switch you made to x.created_at and y.created_at, and put a .reverse at the end

Comment: That works perfectly, Thank U so much for being patient :DDDDD

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `total_votes` is a column in your database.

```
Micropost.where('created_at >= ?', 30.minutes.ago).
  order('total_votes DESC, created_at DESC')
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to first sort by number of votes and if number of votes are same, then you want to sort by created_at.

```
def feed
  @feed_items = Micropost.where("created_at >= ? ", 30.minutes.ago).order('total_votes desc, created_at desc')
end
```

And then, you can use it in your views directly.

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
  <ol class="microposts">
    <%= render @feed_items %>
  </ol>
  <%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank u for answer! Please check newest Edit.